# How to show that a line graph of a graph L(G) has a Euler cycle if the original graph G has a Euler cycle?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

The line graph $L(G)$ of a graph $G$ has a vertex for each edge of $G$, and two of these vertices are adjacent if and only if the corresponding edges in $G$ have a common end vertex.

- (a) Show that $L(G)$ has an Euler cycle if $G$ has an Euler cycle.
- (b) Find a graph $G$ that has no Euler cycle but for which $L(G)$ has an Euler cycle.

I just need a hint here.

What theorems do I use to show (a)?

If I can understand (a) I can definitely do (b) on my own

Comment: Note that graph $H$ has eulerian circuit iff it is connected and every vertex of $H$ has even degree. Try to compute degrees of vertices in $L(G)$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I've figured out a) with your help. I just wish to double check something about b) any graph, G, that is connected and has all odd degree vertices has a L(G) that has a euler cycle while G does not. This means that G does not necessarily have to be a complete graph. It just needs to be a connected graph and have all odd degree vertices correct?